# Interface implementing comparable?

Tags: java, comparable

We are a couple of friends designing a game for fun. In our game we have all enemies implement a `Combatable` interface letting implementors decide how they would like to do combat, this has made the addition of different kinds of enemies very easy. We have (we are at the testing stage) a turret that shoots at the closest enemy every second if that enemy is within range.

We would like to somehow let this interface implement `Comparable<Combatable>` so that we can sort our collection by distance from tower so we only need to check if the first element in the collection is within attackrange. We realized a simple solution would be to create a wrapper class for the combatable that does nothing else besides implement `Comparable` but do we really have to do this? I realize it makes little sense to think of an interface implementing another interface but sense aside it is very convenient for this specific use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface can't **implement** another interface, but it can **extend** any amount of other interfaces.

Just do

```
interface Combatable extends Comparable<Combatable> {
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose this makes sense, sometimes the brain tends to float off the answer but sorting is something we didn't think off when we first started designing. Now we have to implement a method that is 100% identical in every class :d

Comment: @arynaq: Sounds like you could use an abstract class as base.

Answer (score 2):

interface extends another interface but not implements it, because interface won't contain the implementation. So you can just extend comparable.

Answer (score 1):

- Use interfaces to define types.
- Create a new **type** (Measurable) defining Things that are sortable w.r.t a tower (or one if its supertypes such as **Building**) position.
- Then let your **Enemy** class implemet the **Combatable** and **Measurable** interfaces.
  Now your enemies are sortable w.r.t. towers.
- Write your new comparator which sorts Enemies w.r.t. a tower position.

.

```
interface Measurable { 

   // Compute the distance from a turret.
   // It would be better if you use a superclass of Turret to make your method more general
   double distance(Turret p);

};

class Enemy extends Measurable, Combatable {
};

class Turret {

  ...

  Position pos() { return pos; }

  boolean isInRange(Combatable c) { ... }

  void hit(Combatable combatable) { ... }

};



DistFromTurretComparator implements Comparable<Enemy> { 

  DistFromTurretComparator(Turret turret) { 
      this.turret = turret;
  }


  private int compareTo(Enemy other) {
      int dist = distance(turret);
      int oDist = other.distance(turret);

      return  dist > oDist ? + 1 : (dist < oDist ? -1 : 0);
  }

  private final Turret turret;

};

// Main
Tower tower = new Toweer(); 
List<Combatable> enemies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(enemy1, enemy2, ...));

Collections.sort(enemies, new DistFromTurretComparator(tower));
Enemy nearestEnemy = enemies.get(0);


if (tower.hasInRange(enemy)) {
    tower.hit(enemy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an elaborate answer, we might end up doing this.